# How to log SSH activity for every user separately?

Tags: linux, centos7

Is it possible (and how) to log every user activity in their own [username].log (one user can read only his own log)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's possible to do it. I would do it using the rsyslog configuration. He would create a template that dynamically created the logs filas and the directory tree, and would apply the necessary filters. As for reading permissions for each user, it can also be done, I recommend you read the rsyslog configuration. ([rsyslog config](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/properties.html))

**(/etc/rsyslog.conf file or /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf file) You have to restart rsyslog service after doing that**

```
$template SSH_template_user_filter,"/var/log/ssh/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%$HOSTNAME%/auth.log"
:programname, isequal, "sshd";
:msg, contains, "username" -?SSH_template_user_filter
```